# How do I optimize a select query in Activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking to see if there is a better way to write the following ActiveRecord query.

```
@posts = Post.select {|x| x.section.nil?}
```

What I'm doing with this query is searching through posts and just selecting the posts that no longer have sections associated and are left orphaned.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm using rails 3.2.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `Post.where(:section_id => nil)`

Comment: Yeah that's not gonna work because :section_id is not really nil. It actually has a section id that's orphaned. In the above code it checks if the section exists by checking the id of the section and returning the posts with sections that don't exist.

Comment: Try this `Post.includes(:section).where(:section => { :id => nil })`

Comment: @Sontya, since you are using includes (for eager loading), you will have to add reference to that table as well to do query on that included table.

Comment: Yes. So if OP has something like this in `Post` model `has_many :section, :class_name => 'Post', :foreign_key => 'post_id'` then `Post.includes(:section).where(section_posts: { id: nil })` it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Post.joins('left outer join sections on sections.id = posts.section_id').where('sections.id is null and posts.section_id is not null')
```

or in shorter way, using [`eager_load`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load):

```
Post.eager_load(:section).where('sections.id is null and posts.section_id is not null')
```

Comment: Awesome! The first option worked like a charm! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikeR the second should also do its job - and looks nicer, since you don't have to build `join` clause on your own.

Comment: For some reason the second option didn't work. This is what I got: #<Post::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation:0x3febacd11834> I'll just go ahead and use the first. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarekLipka, why do I need to explicitly tell about the left outer join where as includes / eager_load does that for me?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed `includes` doesn't create outer join automatically in this case, you have to use `eager_load`. And I used `eager_load` in the 'second version' of the solution - which doesn't even work, BTW (I wonder why :)).

Comment: @MikeR I think I know why it didn't work - I misspelled `section` association (and used `sections` instead). I leave my answer as it is now, for other users.

Comment: Ok, using eager_load works. When using includes is where it doesn't.

Comment: @MikeR it won't work here, because `includes` by default creates two SQL queries to fetch the records and it creates single query with `outer join` clause only if it knows you want to give `where` clause upon this other table. Since the clause in `where` is string here, Rails can't know what tables you want to use in it, so it creates default two DB queries without join - and there you have an error.

Comment: That's why you need to explicitly tell Rails you want to use `outer join` - and `eager_load` is exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Learned something new. :)